# Pine Script Fill Stop Order Only If Stop Price Was Reached Before Stop Loss

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm building a strategy using Pine Script Version 5.

I'm trying to create a stop order using `strategy.order` command.
The command is working as expected and executes on the next candle if the stop price was reached.

The only issue is that as part of my strategy, the order should be filled only if the price reached the stop price before the intended stop loss price, which means that if the price reaches the stop loss price, it should cancel the stop order and not fill it.

This issue happens only when back-testing, because TradingView does not calculate the intra-bar ticks, on live it will either fill the order or cancel it, but when backtesting it will fill the order even if the high of the candle broke above the intended stop loss price.

I'm trying to find a way to solve it as in the current state the backtest produces false results.

If there is a way to read the future candles (only on history bars) this would solve my issue, but I didn't find a way to do it.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: there are two decisions: 1) use OCA groups (`oca_name`, `oca_type`); 2) manually cancel order by `strategy.cancel()`

Comment: Unfortunately, canceling it is not possible.
It enters the position with the order from previous bar.
When my code is executed on the entry bar, it is already after the order is filled, so I cannot cancel it.

Regarding the oca, I don't see how it can be helpful, can you maybe elaborate more on how would you suggest to use it ?

Comment: Without the source code it is too hard to show. Could you attach the minimal example demonstrating the problem?